# No Perder los Datos de un Formulario al refresh la Pagina Web PHP y HTML

Tags: php, html, formularios, checkbox

El problema lo tengo con unos `input type="checkbox"` de un formulario que al refrescar se pierde la información de si están o no *checked*

*código del checkbox:*

```
 <?php if($_GET[servicio] == 'acabado-con-resina') {
       echo "<input class='service' type='checkbox' value='Acabar con resina'  id='id_services_80' name='check_lista[]'  checked=''>";
 } else {
       echo "<input class='service' type='checkbox' value='Acabar con resina'  id='id_services_80' name='check_lista[]'>";
 }
 ?>
```

Con un `input type="text"` si me funciona bien al refresh la pagina recuerda lo que he escrito, como puedo hacer para que al hacer refresh a la página recuerde los checked y se queden marcados

*código del input type="text":*

```
  <?php if ($_POST[servicio] == '')  {
        echo  "<input type='hidden' name='servicio' class='form-control' placeholder='Pueblo, ciudad' maxlength='100' id='servicio' value='' />";
  } 
  ?>
  <input type="text" name="servicio" class="form-control" placeholder="Acabar con resina" maxlength="100" id="servicio" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['servicio']);?>"/>
```

*también uso este array para determinar que checkbox esta checked*

```
if (is_array($_POST['check_lista'])) {
    $selected = implode(','.PHP_EOL,$_POST['check_lista']).".";
}
```

Gracias y saludos

Comment: ¿Usas Javascript en este contexto? Si es así convendría que agregues el código Javascript a la pregunta.

Comment: también uso este array para determinar que checkbox esta checked     if (is_array($_POST['check_lista'])) {
    $selected = implode(','.PHP_EOL,$_POST['check_lista']).".";
}

Comment: Ya, pero lo normal cuando un formulario se envía es que el mismo se limpie (se borren todos los datos que hay escritos en él). A no ser que quieras impedirlo. El mejor modo de hacerlo es mediante `preventDefault()`, desde Javascript. Por eso te preguntaba si usabas Javascript en este contexto. Me extraña que partes del formulario se limpien y otras no, esto no es normal y podría depender por ejemplo de la configuración del navegador a cuya suerte no deberías dejar el funcionamiento del código (habría tantos contextos como usuarios). Debes controlarlo de forma explícita, mediante código.

Comment: pero si hay varios checkbox en un formulario y marcas dos por ejemplo y luego hay otro campo que es telefono y es obligatorio si no lo escribe ese campo el formulario no se envía y vuelves al formulario para corregir ese error. Y es ahí donde no es normal que se desmarque ya que no se ha enviado, todos los campos pasa eso menos en los checkbox

Comment: es decir recupera todos los campos menos los checkbox

Comment: Agrega el HTML a la pregunta pulsando en [edit].

Answer (score 1):

**Al final el problema ya lo he solucionado con algo tan simple como esto;**

*código del checkbox que estaba usando*

```
<input class='service' type='checkbox' value='Acabar con resina'  id='id_services_80' name='check_lista[]'>
```

Pues resulta que al usar un array con el nombre `name='check_lista[]` no me deja marcarlo como checked.

y al cambiarle el nombre P.ej.  `name='otro_nombre`  si que funciona.

Ahora me surgen otras dudas ya que yo necesito que funcione con el array:

*array que estoy usando*

```
if (is_array($_POST['check_lista'])) {
    $selected = implode(','.PHP_EOL,$_POST['check_lista']).".";
}
```

Pues necesito que el array marque los checkbox como checked , es decir, que deje seleccionados en el formulario los checkbox que selecciona

Gracias